# Spring Boot Retrieving current User

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication

I'm relatively new to Spring Boot and seem to be having problems with connecting another API to current authenticated user.

My main problem is that I want to be able to create a new project using POST method only when user is logged in.

In addition, the project created will have a id attribute that is the current user's pk.

Now I know that there are lots of post relating to this issue but none seem to have been a fix so far thus is why I am requesting for assitance to get a better understanding of the issue.

This is my UserService

```
package portfolio.backend.api.auth.service;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import portfolio.backend.api.auth.Exception.DataNotFoundException;
import portfolio.backend.api.auth.constant.UserType;
import portfolio.backend.api.auth.entity.SiteUser;
import portfolio.backend.api.auth.repository.UserRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public SiteUser create(String username, String userId,
                           String password, String artistType) {
        SiteUser user = new SiteUser();
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setUserId(userId);



        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password));
        user.setArtistType(artistType);
        user.setUserType(UserType.USER);
        this.userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }

    public SiteUser getUser(String username) {
        Optional<SiteUser> siteUser = this.userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (siteUser.isPresent()) {
            return siteUser.get();
        } else {
            throw new DataNotFoundException("siteuser not found");
        }
    }

}
```

With these entities given

```
package portfolio.backend.api.auth.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import portfolio.backend.api.auth.constant.UserType;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;

@Data
@Entity
public class SiteUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @Email
    private String username;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userId;

    private String password;

    private String artistType; 

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserType userType; 

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Finally this is the Project POST method I want to connect with the Id entity in User.

```
@PostMapping
    public Project createProject(Principal principal,
                                 Authentication authentication,
                                 @RequestParam String projectName,
                                
                                 ...
    ) {

        SiteUser siteUser = userService.getUser(authentication.getName());
        Long userId = siteUser.getId();

        Project project = new Project();
        project.setUserId(userId);
        project.setProjectName(projectName);
        ...

        return projectRepository.save(project);
    }
```

These are some of the methods I've tried to retrive the Id

```
// 1
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
SiteUser siteUser = (SiteUser) authentication.getPrincipal();

// 2
SiteUser siteUser = this.userService.getUser(principal.getName());
Long userId = siteUser.getId();

//3
String username = principal.getName();
SiteUser siteUser = this.userService.getUser(username);
Long userId = siteUser.getId();
```

Now when I log in I get this log

```
2023-06-18 11:05:46.141 DEBUG 43426 --- [nio-7072-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        siteuser0_.id as id1_1_,
        siteuser0_.artistType as artistty2_1_,
        siteuser0_.password as password3_1_,
        siteuser0_.userId as userid4_1_,
        siteuser0_.userType as usertype5_1_,
        siteuser0_.username as username6_1_ 
    from
        SiteUser siteuser0_ 
    where
        siteuser0_.username=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        siteuser0_.id as id1_1_,
        siteuser0_.artistType as artistty2_1_,
        siteuser0_.password as password3_1_,
        siteuser0_.userId as userid4_1_,
        siteuser0_.userType as usertype5_1_,
        siteuser0_.username as username6_1_ 
    from
        SiteUser siteuser0_ 
    where
        siteuser0_.username=?
```

Which to me, seems to mean that there is currently an authenticated user.

However, when I send a POST request on Postman
I get the log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at portfolio.backend.api.project.controller.ProjectController.createProject(ProjectController.java:82) ~[main/:na]
```

Which seems to mean that the getName()'s value is Null.
Thank you reading the long post

In addition, below is the logic to my login.

```
package portfolio.backend.api.auth.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import portfolio.backend.api.auth.repository.UserRepository;

import portfolio.backend.api.auth.constant.UserType;

import portfolio.backend.api.auth.entity.SiteUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

   
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<SiteUser> _siteUser = this.userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (_siteUser.isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("NOT FOUND.");
        }

        SiteUser siteUser = _siteUser.get();

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        if ("admin".equals(username)) {

            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(UserType.ADMIN.getValue()));
        } else {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(UserType.USER.getValue()));
            }

            return new User(siteUser.getUsername(), siteUser.getPassword(), authorities);

        }

}
```

Comment: Your approach is correct. You should be able to retrieve current username with SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName(). For You it is null, because your authentication does not work correctly. How do You handle login inside Your app?

Comment: Hey! thanks for responding. I've added the login logic in the last part of the code. Could it be that there is in fact data for the account, but Im not actually logged but rather just showing the information that I entered as username? Im not sure how I should change this ;/